# Get value from table in Excel where another column is non-empty, sorted by date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table in an Excel worksheet which logs my incoming invoices and outgoing expenses - and estimates the tax I owe the IRS.

It looks like this:

```
  A             B                C              D             E             F             G           H
1 [Date      ]  [Type          ] [Received    ] [Received TD] [Expensed   ] [Expensed TD] [Profit TD] [Tax Due               ]
2 (date value)  (text value)     (money value)  =SUM($C$2:C2) (money value) =SUM($E$2:E2) =D2+F2      =ComplicatedFunction(G2)
```

For example:

```
  A             B                 C              D             E             F             G           H
1 [Date       ] [Type           ] [Received    ] [Received TD] [Expensed   ] [Expensed TD] [Profit TD] [Tax Due]
2 2016-04-18    "Invoice paid"         $  100.00     $  100.00                     $  0.00   $  100.00  $  25.00
3 2016-05-10    "Invoice paid"         $  200.00     $  300.00                     $  0.00   $  300.00  $  75.00
4 2016-05-15    "Expense"                            $  300.00       $ 20.00       $ 20.00   $  280.00  $  70.00
5 2016-06-01    "Invoice paid"         $  100.00     $  400.00                     $ 20.00   $  380.00  $  95.00
6 2016-07-05    "Expense"                            $  400.00       $ 50.00       $ 70.00   $  330.00  $  82.50
7               "Invoice Pending"      $  100.00     $  500.00                     $ 70.00   $  430.00  $ 107.50
8               "Invoice Pending"      $  100.00     $  600.00                     $ 70.00   $  530.00  $ 132.50
```

I want to get the last `Tax Due` value which in the table which has a value in the `Date` column (i.e. the current estimate not including pending invoices).

I found this formula to get the last value in a column (I'll confess I don't know how it works - from here: https://exceljet.net/formula/get-value-of-last-non-empty-cell ):

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),A:A)
```

In my case:

```
=LOOKUP( 2, 1 / ( H:H <> "" ), H:H )
```

...however it gives me `$132.50` and not `$82.50`.

In SQL this would be straightforward:

```
SELECT
    TOP 1
    [Tax Due]
FROM
    EstimatedTax
WHERE
    [Date] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    [Date] DESC
```

But what's the Excel equivalent?

Comment: Change the first column Reference to A:A and the second to H:H `=LOOKUP( 2, 1 / ( A:A <> "" ), H:H )`

Comment: @ScottCraner That works, thanks! (I used a table column reference `MyTable[Date]` and `MyTable[Tax Due]` instead of naked column addresses). However I get a warning that `LOOKUP` is deprecated. Is there a way to achieve this using modern idiomatic Excel functions?

Comment: `=INDEX(H:H,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))`